# Database design and large tables?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, normalization

Are tables with lots of columns indicative of bad design? For example say I have the following table that stores user information and user settings:

```
 [Users table]
    userId
    name
    address
    somesetting1
    ...
    somesetting50
```

As the site requires more settings the table gets larger. In my mind this table is normalized, all the settings are dependent on the userId.

I have a thing against tables with lots of columns it just seems wrong to me, but then I remembered that you can select what data to return from the table, so If the table is large I could still break it into several different objects in code. For example

```
[User object]
[UserSetting object]
```

and return only the data to fill those objects.

Is the above common practice, or are their other techniques that deal with tables with lots of columns that are more suitable to use?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use multiple tables like this:

```
[Users table]
   userId
   name
   address

[Settings table]
   settingId
   userId
   settingKey
   settingValue
```

The tables are related by the userId column which you can use to retrieve the settings for the user you need to.

Comment: I would prefer to forego the `settingId` column (which is presumably your primary key) and use the natural key `(userId, settingKey)`.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it is bad table design. If a user doesn't have an entry for 47 of those 50 settings then you will have a large number of NULL's in the table which isn't good practice and will also slow down performance (NULL's have to be handled in a special way).

Instead, have the following:

USER TABLE
Id,
FirstName
LastName
etc

SETTINGS
Id,
SettingName

USER SETTINGS
Id,
SettingId,
UserId,
SettingValue

You then have a many to many join, and eliminate NULL's

Answer (score 1):

first, don't put spaces in table names! all the [braces] will be a real pain!

if you have 50 columns how meaningful will all that data be for each user? will there be lots of nulls? Most data may not even apply to any given user.  Think 1 to 1 tables, where you break down the "settings" into logical groups:

```
Users:              --main table where most values will be stored
    userId
    name
    address
    somesetting1    ---please note that I'm using "somesetting1", don't
    ...             --- name the columns like this, use meaningful names!!
    somesetting5

UserWidgets         --all widget settings for the user
    userId
    somesetting6
    ....
    somesetting12

UserAccounting      --all accounting settings for the user
    userId
    somesetting13
    ....
    somesetting23

--etc..
```

you only need to have a `Users` row for each user, and then a row in each table where that data applies to the given user.  I f a user doesn't have any widget settings then no row for that user.  You can LEFT join each table as necessary to get all the settings as needed.  Usually you only need to work on a sub set of settings based on which part of the application that is running, which means you won't need to join in all of the tables, just the one or tow that you need at that time.

Comment: So the above tables would be 1-to-1 relationships in the database? I was thinking of doing something similar but instead have one large table (their won't be any nulls fields) and break it into different classes and only query data required to fill the classes. Would it be better to use separate tables or one table for that scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You could consider an attributes table. As long as your indexes are good, then you wouldn't have too much of a performance issue:

```
[AttributeDef]
   AttributeDefId int (primary key)
   GroupKey varchar(50)
   ItemKey varchar(50)
   ...

[AttributeVal]
   AttributeValId int (primary key)
   AttributeDefId int (FK -> AttributeDef.AttributeDefId)
   UserId int (probably FK to users table?)
   Val varchar(255)
   ...
```

basically you're "pivoting" your table with many columns into 2 tables with less columns.  You can write views and table functions around this structure to give you data for a group of related items or just a specific item, etc.  You could also add other things to the attribute definition table to indicate required data elements, restrictions on the data elements, etc.

What's your thought on this type of design?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand it too well, but I'm not crazy about this approach :(

Answer (score -1):

Use several tables with matching indexes to get the best SELECT speed. Use the indexes as a way to relate the information between tables using a JOIN.